# .htaccess .gif to x1.php

Tags: linux, .htaccess

I want to redirect .gif to x1.php.  For some reason it is not working

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .(gif)$ x1.php [NC]
```

What exactly is wrong here?

Comment: Try escaping the `.`, like `\.`. You might also want to put a `^` at the beginning of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try to obmit the () and also mask the dot.

```
RewriteRule \.gif$ x1.php [NC]
```